# Insert en store procedure no inserta los datos pero tapoco me da error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

El error es que me devuelve la cantidad de filas afectadas, pero luego realizando un select en la base de datos no aparece lo agregado y nose en que falle, porque la cantidad de filas que devuelve son las mismas que hay en la DataTable que le envio y no me da el error en el ExecuteNonQuery.

Este es el tipo que cree

```
 CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TipoProducto6] AS TABLE(
    [idUsuario] [char](255) NULL,
    [idProducto] [char](255) NULL,
    [Cantidad] [char](255) NULL,
    [Talle] [char](255) NULL,
    [PrecioUnitario] [char](255) NULL,
    [PrecioTotal] [char](255) NULL
```

)
GO

y este es el Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertarPedido]

@DTItems AS [dbo].[TipoProducto6] READONLY

AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Pedidos] (
       idUsuario,
       idProducto,
       Cantidad,
       Talle,
       PrecioUnitario,
       PrecioTotal
)
SELECT CONVERT(INT, idUsuario) AS idUsuario,
       CONVERT(INT, idProducto) AS idProducto,
       CONVERT(INT, Cantidad) AS Cantidad,
       CONVERT(CHAR(5), Talle) AS Talle,
       CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), PrecioUnitario) AS PrecioUnitario, 
       CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),PrecioTotal) AS PrecioTotal 
FROM @DTItems
END
GO
```

Esto me devuelve el SQL Profiler

```
declare @p1 dbo.TipoProducto6
insert into @p1 values(N'2',N'2',N'5',N'32',N'10000.00',N'50000.00')

exec insertarPedido @DTItems=@p1
```

Lo cual si lo copio y lo pego en una consulta a mano inserta los datos.

Adjunto imagenes donde muestro los datos enviados y las filas que retorna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parecerá algo tonto (pero sucede) ¿Estás seguro que estás revisando en la misma base de datos en la que estás insertando? A veces es bueno revisar ambas cadenas de conexión. También puedes usar el Profiler para verificar que se está ejecutando el código en SQL Server y si pasa algo más.

Comment: La base de datos que estoy usando es la correcta, use el Profiler y declara el tipo Tabla correspondiente, realiza el insert y luego me ejecuta el exec insertarPedido eso nose si deberia ser asi @LuisCazares

Comment: Nunca había visto un insert into sin el values, probaste directamente tu stored procedure, o no verificaste que funciona desde SQL?

Comment: Yo tampoco, pero sabia que se le podía enviar parametros en forma de tabla e insertarlos solo que no sabia como me guie por esta pagina https://gherbust.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/pasar-in-datatable-a-un-storeprocedure-con-c/ @Daniel

Comment: @Daniel así es como se hace para insertar múltiples filas al mismo tiempo. El código del procedimiento se ve correcto. No sé que pueda ser el problema.

Comment: No veo el Commit de la transacción. Antes del return de las filas, debes agregar una llamada transaccion.Commit();

Comment: Era eso si GRACIAS estuve 2 dias investigando el porque @JavierReséndiz

Answer (score 0):

Debes manejar los values en el sp, y si los datos vienen de alguna fuente como formulario o archivo debes declarar los parametros, seria algo como esto:

```
ALTER PROC SP_Name ( @campo1 varchar(45), @campo2 int, @campo3
varchar(20) ) AS  BEGIN INSERT INTO tabla ( campo1, campo2, campo3 )
VALUES ( @campo1, @campo2, @campo3 ) END
```